# AngularFire2 Saving a DataURI as a file for Firebase Storage

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, data-uri

I am currently using the [ng2-img-cropper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-img-cropper) to crop a profile photo the user submits to my Angular2 app. However, the image cropper saves the file as a data URI like this: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA...`

However, I need to have that variable be saved as a File type and not a string type so I can upload it to my firebase database using `firebase.storage().ref('reference').put(imageFile)`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, i found one solution that worked for me:

```
var ref = this.storage.ref("profile.png").putString(this.croppedImage, 'data_url');
ref.downloadURL().subscribe(url => {
  console.log(url);
});
```

Note that the "secret" here is the 'data_url' (in lowercase): without it, it does not save the data as an image, but as an octet-stream.